# How can I correctly print a date in a twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

Some of my tables contain date fields and some values are set to: '0000-00-00', when I try to print the date in a twig template like this:

```
{{ entity.date | date('m/d/Y') }}
```

I get the following exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed
to parse time string (-001-11-30T00:00:00-06:00) at position 7 (-): 
Double timezone specification") in MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_estimates.html.twig at line 12.
```

- **How can I handle the printing of these dates?**
- **Will it be better if I map the 'date' type to string?**

Comment: I get these kind of returns when using a serializer for dates that are unset or `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Maybe you could create an intermediate filter that would return a null or an actual \DateTime and then follow that with a ternary like `{{ entity.date|date_check is null ? "" : entity.date|date_check|date("m/d/Y") }}`

Comment: Should I nullify dates in the getter method within the entity class?

Comment: To be honest I had never thought of doing that. That would probably be a far easier approach than either making a function for every bundle or having to have every one of your bundles dependent on another.

Comment: Ok then, I will give it a try.

Comment: After having a mess around I don't think nulling the date through getters would be of any use as, from my "testing", I have found that the entity data is taken directly from the class property rather than via the getter.

Comment: I was about to start testing but I'll take your word for it. What about the twig extension by MidoDev? For whatever reason I don't think it's addressing the problem, I think it gives the same result as if I use the twig date filter, right?

Comment: @MidoDev's function doesn't makes sense as I have just stated in my reply to it. You could, however, follow that format but then just use `return $dateTime > new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:01')? $dateTime : null ;`. This checks is the supplied date is after `0000-00-00 00:00:01` (1 second after nothing) or not and then return the $dateTime or `null`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date filter accepts strings (it must be in a format supported by the strtotime function), DateTime instances, 
[enter link description here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html)

You can create a twig extension

```
<?php 


use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
use CG\Core\ClassUtils;


class PostExtension extends \Twig_Extension{

    protected $loader;
    protected $controller;

    public function __construct(FilesystemLoader $loader)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;
    }

    public function setController($controller)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'dateFormater' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'dateFormater', array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function dateFormater($dateTime){

        $now = new \DateTime('NOW');
        return $now->format( 'd-m-Y' ); // any other format !!               
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'some_extension';
    }


}
```

now add it as a service !

```
 <services>
        <service id="twig.extension.postExtension" class="Project\PostBundle\Twig\Extension\PostExtension" public="false">
            <tag name="twig.extension" />
            <argument type="service" id="twig.loader" />
        </service>

        <service id="project.post.listener" class="Project\PostBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener">
            <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.controller" method="onKernelController" />
            <argument type="service" id="twig.extension.postExtension" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

so finally you can use it as a filter in your twig code

```
{{ dateFormater(entity.date) }}
```

enjoy !

Comment: Your function takes a variable of `dateTime` and then ignores it and returns a `\DateTime` object set to now. I feel you probably missed something in this answer.

Comment: Basically i gave him a generic solution and he have just to adapt this code to his context.

Comment: How does it address the problem of date which only contains zeros?